# Rouches for $z^2-z+2$ in the annulus $1<|z|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis

For $z^2-z+2$ in the annulus $1<|z|<2$. From wolfram alpha both of its zeroes are in there.

**Attempt**

In $|z|=2$,

- The choice $f(z)=z^{2}$ doesn't work since $|f-g|=|z-2|$ is equal to 4 for $z=-2$.
- The choice $f(z)=z^2+2$ doesn't work since $|f-g|=2$ and $z^2+2=2$ for $z=2e^{i\pi/2}$.
- The choice $f(z)=z^2+z$ doesn't work since $|f-g|=2$ and $|z||z-1|\geq 2$

In $|z|=1$

- The choice f(z)=2 doesn't work since $|f-g|=|z-1|$ which is equal to 2 for $z=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your ideas correctly:

Setting $g(z)=z^2-z+2 = (z-\frac12)^2+\frac74$ we may compare with $f(z)=(z-1/2)^2$ for the contour $|z|=2$  where $|g(z)-f(z)| =\frac74< \frac94=(\frac32)^2\leq ||z|-\frac12|^2\leq |f(z)|$.

For $|z|=1$ not so clear if you don't want to consider $f$ of more or less the same form as $g$.